# What would you call a real market that is close to perfect competition?

Tags: competition, definition

I want to explain perfect competition to students using a few practical examples without going into much of the theory. But I want it to be theoretically accurate and I don't want to claim that those are examples of 'perfect competition'. I am thinking about calling it 'near perfect competition', but I wonder if there is a conventional term for a market that is close to perfect competition. [This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_competition) mentions 'close-to-perfect competition' but I'm not sure if that's a conventional term.

Comment: Is "efficient" not strong enough for what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard term for what you'd want to refer to. I'd consider the following good candidates though:

- Near-perfect / almost-perfect / close-to-perfect / epsilon-perfect competition (the last of course comes from the notion of [epsilon-equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon-equilibrium) in game theory)
- Markets with low concentration, or lowly / sparsely concentrated markets (based on the empirical measure of [concentration ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_ratio#Concentration_levels))

Answer (score 6):

I do not have a special term, but I give this analogy:

> We know what a triangle is. But in the real world, it is impossible to draw a perfect triangle and there do not exist examples of perfect triangles.
>
> Similarly, we have just learnt what perfect competition is. But in the real world, there do not exist examples of perfect competition. Nonetheless, here are some examples of real-world markets that come "close to" perfect competition ...
>
> We stress that these markets are not actual examples of perfect competition. (To repeat, such examples do not exist.) Instead, these are merely examples that come "close to" perfect competition.

Comment: This is a great explanation, I will definitely use it. You have my thanks and upvote, but I got to accept the answer by Herr K because I really need a word for it not just for explaining, but for much less exciting administrative purposes of naming lessons, experiment apps etc.